# Why My service don t work in the Backgroung?

Tags: java, android, service, background

Im working on an taxi app that need to keep tracking driver even when the app is in background or the screen is off
I tried to do it through a Service but it dons t work and I cant find the probleme

My second issue it that the app don t upload some kind of images for example whene i take a high quality photo with my phone and i upload it in the server the app keep saying failed but the photo is uploaded on the server / and whene i take a screenshot un upload it it work fine

3Q/ what are the minimun requemendation of a server to use with a taxi app

this is the MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {



/** MAP **/
public static GoogleMap mMap;
public static Location currentLocation;

/** GOOGLE API CLIENT **/
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000, FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // = 5 seconds
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
public static String amount,id_ride,position,id_driver,note_,img,comment;

public static AlertDialog alertDialog;
private static TextView title;
private static final String HTTPS = "https://";
private static final String HTTP = "http://";

private static TextView ok, time;
private static ProgressBar progressBar2;
private static CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = MainActivity.this;
    activity = this;
    connectionDetector=new ConnectionDetector(context);
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Bundle objetbundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String fragment_name = objetbundle.getString("fragment_name");

    if(!fragment_name.equals("")){
        notification = true;
        if(fragment_name.equals("ridenewrider"))
            selectItem(1);
        else if(fragment_name.equals("ridecompleted"))
            selectItem(4);
            /*else if(fragment_name.equals("ridecanceledrider"))
                selectItem(1);*/
    }

    balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance);
    user_photo = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_photo);
    switch_statut = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch_statut);
    user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    user_phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
    statut_conducteur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statut_conducteur);
    drawer_conducteur = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_conducteur);
    drawer_user = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_user);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationViewLeft = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvdrawer);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    setDrawer();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if(fragment_name.equals(""))
            selectItem(0);
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    if(!isLocationEnabled(context))
        showMessageEnabledGPS();

    balance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (M.getStatutConducteur(context).equals("yes")) {
        switch_statut.setChecked(true);
        statut_conducteur.setText("enabled");
    } else {
        switch_statut.setChecked(false);
        statut_conducteur.setText("disabled");
    }

    switch_statut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(switch_statut.isChecked()) {
                M.showLoadingDialog(context);
                new changerStatut().execute("yes");
            }else {
                M.showLoadingDialog(context);
                new changerStatut().execute("no");
            }
        }
    });

    if(!M.getPhoto(context).equals("")) {
        Glide.with(context).load(AppConst.Server_url + "images/app_user/" + M.getPhoto(context))
                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        user_photo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_profile));
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(user_photo);
    }else{
        user_photo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_profile));
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    if (provider != null) {
        currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

    updateFCM(M.getID(context));
}

public static void setTitle(String title_){
    title.setText(title_);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(context, PayPalService.class));
    currentLocation = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

/** Récupération user wallet**/
public class getWallet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = AppConst.Server_url+"get_wallet.php";
        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject msg = json.getJSONObject("msg");
                            String etat = msg.getString("etat");
                            if(etat.equals("1")){
                                balance.setText(M.getCurrency(context)+" "+msg.getString("amount"));
                            }else{

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id_user", M.getID(context));
                params.put("cat_user", M.getUserCategorie(context));
                return params;
            }

        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (this != null) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.currentLocation = location;

    if (currentLocation != null) {
        new setCurrentLocation().execute(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }
}

/** Update driver position  **/
private class setCurrentLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = AppConst.Server_url+"set_position.php";
        final String latitude = params[0];
        final String longitude = params[1];
        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id_user", M.getID(context));
                params.put("user_cat", M.getUserCategorie(context));
                params.put("latitude", latitude);
                params.put("longitude", longitude);
                return params;
            }

        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (this != null) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
}

/** Start COOGLE API Client **/
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&  ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    // Permissions ok, we get last location
    currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    startLocationUpdates();
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&  ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

/** Change driver status **/
private class changerStatut extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = AppConst.Server_url+"change_statut.php";
        final String online = params[0];
        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            M.hideLoadingDialog();
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject msg = json.getJSONObject("msg");
                            String etat = msg.getString("etat");
                            String online = msg.getString("online");
                            if(etat.equals("1")){
                                if(online.equals("yes")) {
                                    switch_statut.setChecked(true);
                                    statut_conducteur.setText("enabled");
                                    M.setStatutConducteur(online,context);
                                }else {
                                    switch_statut.setChecked(false);
                                    statut_conducteur.setText("disabled");
                                    M.setStatutConducteur(online,context);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                M.hideLoadingDialog();
                if(switch_statut.isChecked())
                    switch_statut.setChecked(false);
                else
                    switch_statut.setChecked(true);
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id_driver", M.getID(context));
                params.put("online", online);
                return params;
            }

        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //to add spacing between cards
        if (this != null) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if(!isLocationEnabled(context))
                showMessageEnabledGPS();
            return;
        }

    }
}

public void showMessageEnabledGPSClient(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.this_service_requires_the_activation_of_the_gps))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void showMessageEnabledGPS(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Activez le service GPS pour partager votre position avec les clients. Activez le GPS maintenant ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context){
    boolean enabled = false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
        enabled = (mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
    }else{
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        enabled =  service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)||service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    return enabled;
}
```

and this is the Service

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    public static Location currentLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    public static Context context;


    
    @Override

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    &&  ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
}

            currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            startLocationUpdates();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

        private void startLocationUpdates() {
            locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    &&  ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            }

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, (LocationListener) this);

        }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what version of android the app is running on services get killed when the app is in the background. To stop that you need to start the service using `startForeground`

Comment: Is my code correcct ? and are the other methode to do it ?

Comment: you dont use start foreground so...no

Comment: do u mean that i need to set a start button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation on Android service starting Android O. Android OS kills the long running background services/processes after some time for battery optimization (explained here https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/background-services-in-android-o-a38a7c624391 & https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c).

Instead you can use [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) to keep your app running in the background. Foreground service requires a continuous Notification to be displayed so that user will be aware that X app is doing some work in background. For Foreground service implementation you can refer https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service.

Comment: that was helpful . i tried this method as in the video . but still not know how to add locationUpdate on it / i set a foregroung service with notification that can keep running in backgroung but not the service that i need / plz explain

Comment: Service without notification are restricted by Android for sake of battery optimization. If your app is doing something in the background then user should be aware of it (that's why notification). Plus to add locationUpdate you can use the same code for location update in your new foreground service. or refer https://github.com/android/location-samples/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java implementation.

Comment: i tried your method but still have some issues , pls take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582706/how-to-request-locationupdate-method-in-foreground-service